# javascript function like stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript

I don't want to use jquery in my code so is there (or how to define) a function like stopPropagation() in javascript without using jquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery just wraps the [method of the same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) on the native DOM event object.

So, `event.stopPropagation()`

See also, [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopPropagation).

Comment: what I understand from you that I can use stopPropagation() without including jquery in my document?

Comment: @user3926604 — Yes, you just call it on a DOM event object instead of a jQuery event object.

Comment: @Quentin It seems that there is an error in my javascript code because stopPropagation() is not working.Anyway, thanks for your reply.